# How to use google sheet to check URL availability?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

is it possible to write a google App script in google sheets to check if a set of URLs are working normally? I want to check if there's any stock available to sell for each URL. Many thanks!!!

[This URL means out of stock and it's not available](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5euxB.jpg)

[This URL means stock available and the link is working properly](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zTbe0.jpg)

Comment: I think that in your situation, at first, it is required to confirm whether the HTML data you want to retrieve can be retrieved using Google Apps Script. Because when the HTML data is created by Javascript, your goal cannot be directly achieved. How about this?

Comment: Hi Tanaike, thanks for the reply. I a total noob to this, may I know how to know if the HTML data can be retrieved using Google Apps Script please?

Comment: Thank you for replying. For example, how about checking it using `UrlFetchApp.fetch(url)`? [Ref](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/url-fetch/url-fetch-app#fetchurl) When `DriveApp.createFile(UrlFetchApp.fetch(url).getBlob().setName("sample.txt"))` is used, the HTML data is saved as a file. You can confirm whether the value you want to retrieve is included in the saved file. When the value is included, I think that your goal can be achieved.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.